# NGINX reverse-proxy with SSL certificate gives SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER error only in Firefox

Tags: ssl, nginx

I've configured an NGINX reverse-proxy with SSL certificate and it works fine in Chrome and IE, but give me an SSL error (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER) in Firefox. 
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found [another answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082856/3606250) that explains that **this happens if the certificate chain is not fully sent by the server (or in this case the load balancer)**.

This other answer explains that Chrome looks for this missing chain certificates by itself while Firefox does not. Actually Firefox caches intermediate certificates from earlier connections to other sites, but in my case since I'm mostly using Chrome, Firefox didn't had any cache of these Sectigo (Comodo) root certificates, that's why I was getting the validation error.

When I purchased my PositiveSSL certificate I've received both the "crt" file for my domain but also a "ca-bundle" file which is the **certification authority bundle**. **Both these files should be concatenated (first my certificate, followed by the certificates for the authority chain), and this combined file is what should be configured as ssl_certificate in NGINX.**